# Function push not working in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, push

I have this:

```
angular.module("delivery",[]);
angular.module("delivery").controller("productsControl",function($scope,$http,$log){
$scope.produtos=[];
$scope.cart=[{id:'1',produto:'zero',valor:'0.0'}];
var productsLoad = function(){
        $http.get("json-produtos.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.produtos=data;
    });
};
$scope.addToCart = function(pid,pnome,pvalor){
    var temp=[{id:'\''+pid+'\'',produto:'\''+pnome+'\'',valor:'\''+pvalor+'\''}];
    $scope.cart.push(angular.copy(temp));
    alert(temp[0]['id']);
};
productsLoad();
```

});

I added one entry for cart[] for tests purposes.

My html is:

```
<div id="box" ng-repeat="item in produtos">
        <img src="thumb.php?img={{item.foto}}&x=75&y=75" />
        <div id="titulo"><p>{{item.produto}}</p><span>{{item.descricao}}</span></div>
        <div id="valor">R$ {{item.valor}}</div>
        <div id="add" ng-click="addToCart(item.id,item.produto,item.valor);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="last"></div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="prod in cart" style="background-color:yellow">
    <div id="titulo"><p>{{prod.produto}}</p><span>{{prod.id}}</span></div>
    <div id="valor">R$ {{prod.valor}}</div>
</div>
```

The correct valaues are being passed by addToCart(), I can see the correct value in js, but the new entry never is "pushed" to cart[];

Comment: Oh.. I almost forget, this line:
      var temp=[{id:'\''+pid+'\'',produto:'\''+pnome+'\'',valor:'\''+pvalor+'\''}];
was like this
   var temp=[{id:pid,produto:pnome,valor:pvalor}];

I changed it when testing.

Comment: why are you doing this?  `var temp=[{id:'\''+pid+'\'',produto:'\''+pnome+'\'',valor:'\''+pvalor+'\''}];` instead of just this:  `var temp=[{id:pid, produto:pnome, valor: pvalor}];` ???

Comment: Your var temp in the addToCart function is an array. It looks like you're pushing that whole array to cart instead of just the object. You probably want to remove the [] from that variable. 

var temp = {...}

Comment: I think @Mathew is right, you should be pushing an object to the collection(array of objects), try removing the square brackets from the `temp` assignation. Edit: damn I'm slow tonight

Comment: Oh my! Yeap... just removed [] and it worked! Thank you all!